# How to fix LDAPSocketReceiveError: error receiving data: The read operation timed out while using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN/1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941?

Tags: python, linux, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to fetch user's group's recursively.
For eg: User A is part of G1 and G1 is part of G2, I should get G1 and G2 as the output for A.

My code is as below.

```
query = "(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=nn\, rr,OU=tt,OU=uu,OU=mm,OU=ss,OU=bb,OU=ss,OU=ll,DC=aa,DC=ss,DC=com))"
tls = ldap3.Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
server = ldap3.Server(<<domaincontroller>>, get_info=ldap3.ALL, mode=ldap3.IP_V4_PREFERRED, tls=tls, use_ssl=True)
with ldap3.Connection(server=server,authentication=ldap3.NTLM,auto_bind=True,password=domain.password,read_only=True,receive_timeout=self.config.ldap_timeout,user=domain.user) as ldap_connection:
    search_parameters = {'search_base': domain.base_dn,'search_filter': ldap_query_find_all_groups_with_our_user_as_member,'attributes': ['*']}
    ldap_connection.search(**search_parameters)
    print(ldap_connection.entries)
```

It is working fine without the :1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:, but with it, I am getting error as below.

**Note:**
There are chances of `duplicacy` also, where Parent has a group as its child and the Child has same group as its child again.
Also, although I don't know exactly there could be possibilities where 2 groups are a part of each other and cause a deadlock. I am not sure if LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN handles such situations.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 82, in receiving
    data = self.connection.socket.recv(self.socket_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 994, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 871, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 633, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/app/core.py", line 283, in smita
    ldap_connection.search(**search_parameters)
  File "/opt/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 789, in search
    response = self.post_send_search(self.send('searchRequest', request, controls))
  File "/opt/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 139, in post_send_search
    responses, result = self.get_response(message_id)
  File "/opt/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 324, in get_response
    responses = self._get_response(message_id)
  File "/opt/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 157, in _get_response
    responses = self.receiving()
  File "/opt/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 92, in receiving
    raise communication_exception_factory(LDAPSocketReceiveError, type(e)(str(e)))(self.connection.last_error)
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketReceiveError: error receiving data: The read operation timed out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timeout, in general, means that the server did not respond in the expected amount of time, so the client gave up waiting. This can be a time-consuming query. Try increasing `receive_timeout` to allow more time for it to return the results.